# Fixing CROSS APPLY function- one row to multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, cross-apply

I’ve been trying to find a way to split my rows into multiple rows. I came across a CROSS APPLY example and tried to recreate it. I was able to do this, however, I cannot get anything to filter from the WHERE clause. The code looks messy, so I am wondering if I need to just trying a nesting function or something completely different? No matter if I change the first where clause, the second where clause, or both WHERE clauses, the filtering does not occur (*such as removing Terry Johnson because TYPE column says ‘LOT’*). I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and I have been looking everywhere for an answer or alternative to CROSS APPLY. I may not be searching the correct words for what I need. If you can help point me in the direction, that would be great. Thanks!

[all three tables as a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiCNc.png)

*My original data looks like this:*

**Div------- Job #-------   Type----    Sales Agent---  Cancel Date---  Contract Approved Date**
 
    CAE----- Aaab-001---    SNGL--- Joe Smith--------   02/01/2018------    01/15/2018
    CLT-----    Eeef-203-----   DUPL--- Jane Smiths---- 05/28/2018-------   05/02/2018
    CAE---- Zzzz-101-----   LOT-----    Terry Johnson-----  (blank)----------   06/01/2018

*Output looks like this:*
**Div------- Job #-------   Type----    Sales Agent---  Cancel Date---  Contract Approved Date**
 
    CAE----- Aaab-001---    SNGL--- Joe Smith--------   Null----------------    01/15/2018
    CAE----- Aaab-001---    SNGL--- Joe Smith------ 02/01/2018-------   Null
 CLT-----   Eeef-203-----   DUPL--- Jane Smiths---- Null----------------    05/02/2018
 CLT-----   Eeef-203-----   DUPL--- Jane Smiths---- 05/28/2018-------   Null
   CAE----  Zzzz-101-----   LOT-----    Terry Johnson-----  (blank)----------   06/01/2018

*Want data to look like this (by filtering out LOT):*
**Div------- Job #-------   Type----    Sales Agent---  Cancel Date---  Contract Approved Date**
 
    CAE----- Aaab-001---    SNGL--- Joe Smith--------   Null----------------    01/15/2018
    CAE----- Aaab-001---    SNGL--- Joe Smith------ 02/01/2018-------   Null
 CLT-----   Eeef-203-----   DUPL--- Jane Smiths---- Null----------------    05/02/2018
 CLT-----   Eeef-203-----   DUPL--- Jane Smiths---- 05/28/2018-------   Null

```
SELECT
[Ounit Code] AS "Div",
[Project Code] + '-' + [Lot] AS [Job #],
[Sales Agent],
cr.[Cancel Date],
cr.[Contract Approved Date]

FROM [dbo].[Sales Summ] AS ss

CROSS APPLY  (VALUES
    ([Cancel Date],NULL),
    (NULL,[Contract Approved Date]))

    CR ([Cancel Date], [Contract Approved Date])

WHERE ss.[Cancel Date] IS NOT NULL AND ss.[Contract Approved Date] IS NOT NULL
      AND TYPE <> ‘LOT’

UNION

SELECT  
[Ounit Code] AS "Div",
[Project Code] + '-' + [Lot] AS [Job #],
[Sales Agent],
ss.[Cancel Date],
ss.[Contract Approved Date]

FROM [dbo].[Sales Summ] AS ss
WHERE ss.[Cancel Date] IS NULL OR ss.[Contract Approved Date] IS NULL
      AND TYPE <> ‘LOT’
```

Comment: Based on that screenshot. That expected result is just the first query from the UNION. So what if you remove the union and the select under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Div VARCHAR(10), [Job #] VARCHAR(20),Type VARCHAR(20), [Sales Agent] VARCHAR(20), [Cancel Date] DATE, [Contract Approved Date] DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
('CAE', 'Aaab-001', 'SNGL', 'Joe Smith', '02/01/2018','01/15/2018'),
('CLT', 'Eeef-203', 'DUPL', 'Jane Smiths', '05/28/2018','05/02/2018'),
('CAE', 'Zzzz-101', 'LOT', 'Terry Johnson', NULL, '06/01/2018')


select Div , [Job #] ,Type , [Sales Agent] , X.[Cancel Date] , X.[Contract Approved Date] 
FROM @Table 
 CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ([Cancel Date], NULL) , (NULL, [Contract Approved Date] )) X ([Cancel Date] , [Contract Approved Date] ) 
WHERE Type <> 'LOT'
```

Result:

```
Div        Job #                Type                 Sales Agent          Cancel Date Contract Approved Date
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------------------
CAE        Aaab-001             SNGL                 Joe Smith            2018-02-01  NULL
CAE        Aaab-001             SNGL                 Joe Smith            NULL        2018-01-15
CLT        Eeef-203             DUPL                 Jane Smiths          2018-05-28  NULL
CLT        Eeef-203             DUPL                 Jane Smiths          NULL        2018-05-02
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am still learning and wasn't sure how the UNION was working with the CROSS APPLY and this is better.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` should work :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ( (SELECT Div, Job, Type, SalesAgent, NULL as CancelDate, ContractApprovedDate
        FROM [dbo].[Sales Summ]
       ) UNION ALL
       (SELECT Div, Job, Type, SalesAgent, CancelDate, NULL as ContractApprovedDate
        FROM [dbo].[Sales Summ]
       )
     ) t
WHERE t.type <> 'LOT';
```